# Disable man / nroff's mangling of quotes and dashes

Tags: command-line, locale

TDLR:

How do I disable the magic parsing of the `'` and the `-` inside of `foo-bar`:

```bash
❯ echo "\'hello\' --foo-bar" | nroff
´hello´ ‐‐foo‐bar
^     ^      ^ are not the original input
```

Long:

My `man` page mangles dashes and quotes when rendering `us-ascii` as UTF-8:

Example shown: `ripgrep` (`rg`):

```bash
❯ man rg | grep -- ', --after'
       -A NUM, --after‐context=NUM
#                     ^ this is not U+002D, it is U+2010

❯ man rg | grep -- ', --after-'
#                            ^ when I add the dash it doesn't find anything as they are not the same
```

However, searching in the man page itself it is just a normal (`U+002D`) dash:

```bash
❯ cat rg.1 | grep -- 'after-context'
\fB\-A\fP \fINUM\fP, \fB\-\-after-context\fP=\fINUM\fP
```

This completely breaks my searching inside of man as typing `/after-<enter>` yields nothing. My keyboard does not have a `U+2010` button, nor should I have to care about the intricacies of the difference between a soft hyphen (`U+00AD`), a modifier letter minus sign (`U+02D7`), a hyphen (`U+2010`), a non-breaking hyphen (`U+2011`), a figure dash (`U+2012`), an en dash (`U+2013`), a hyphenation point (`U+2027`), a hyphen bullet (`U+2043`), a minus sign (`U+2212`), or roman uncia sign (`U+10191`), or whatever way `man` choses to render render the characters.

The same applies to quotes. For some reason `man` changes the normal quotes to an open & close quote:

```bash
❯ man rg | grep -- 'path:none'
               --colors ’path:none’ \
               --colors ’path:none’ \
#                       |         ^ not U+0027 but U+2019
#                       ^ not U+0027 but U+2019
```

This one is actually worse as it renders both as a right single quotation mark.

Again, the source uses a normal `U+0027`.

```bash
❯ cat rg.1 | grep -- 'path:none'
    \-\-colors 'path:none' \\
    \-\-colors 'path:none' \\
```

How can I disable this behavior?

Using `nroff -Tlatin1` does not work when the `man` page itself contains UTF-8 characters.

Version & locale:

```
❯ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=23.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=mantic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 23.10"

❯ locale
LANG=C.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="C.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="C.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

Comment: FWIW, it's not man that's at fault. https://lwn.net/Articles/947941/

Comment: I cannot reproduce this unless I pipe the greps through nroff... Otherwise it works for me just as you desire. My LANG=en_US.UTF-8 and I am on 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

nroff does interpret these characters in ways you don't want. Consider using a pre-processing step with sed to replace or remove special characters before passing the text to nroff.

You could try this one:

```
echo "\'hello\' --foo-bar" | sed 's/--/\\&/g' | nroff
```

This sed command replaces -- with -- before passing the text to nroff, which might help in preventing nroff from interpreting it as a special sequence.